# use the output of notebook1 in notebook2

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-databricks, dbutils

I have defined the class in  `notebook2` which should take the parameters from the `notebook1`. Because of that reason Im using the `dbutils.notebook.run(path, 60, {"CATALOG": f"{CATALOG}"})` command to call  `notebook2`. Note that with `%run` i was not able to pass the parameters using the  widgets.

Now, I dont have problem with passing the parameters but the function I have defined in my class I want to use them in `notebook1` but I cant. As I understand, `dbutils.notebook.run` start new spark session in `notebook2` and thats the reason why I get the error that `name 'gpg_encryption' is not defined`.

Here is what Im doing:

**1.** running `notebook1`

`dbutils.notebook.run(path, 60, {"CATALOG": f"{CATALOG}", "STORAGEACCOUNT_NAME": f"{STORAGEACCOUNT_NAME}"})`

**2.**

Above code tiggering `notebook2` and the class defined in there

```
  class gpg_encryption(gnupg.GPG):
  """
  Expands the GnuPG library:
  - Importing of BASE64 encoded keys.
  - Decrypting csv files to pandas dataframes.
  - Using simplified key-management.
  On databricks clusters.
  """
  
  asc_key_path = f'/Volumes/{CATALOG}/bronze/private'
  
  def __init__(self):
    self.gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    self.gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
    self.create_key_path_dir()
    
  def create_key_path_dir(self):
    """
    Creates a folder to store keyfiles.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(self.asc_key_path):
      spark.sql(f"CREATE EXTERNAL VOLUME lakehouse_dev.bronze.private LOCATION 'abfss://bronze@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/private'")
```

**3.** After class is defined, in the same notebook (`notebook2`), running this command to  get the output of the class in `notebook1`

`dbutils.notebook.exit(gpg_encryption)`

**4.** As a last step

running in `notebook1`

`gpg_handler = gpg_encryption()`

But I get the error

> name 'gpg_encryption' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I just have expanded my `init` function as below

```
  def __init__(self, storage_account, catalog):
    self.gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    self.gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
    self.storage_account = storage_account
    self.catalog = catalog
    self.asc_key_path = f'/Volumes/{self.catalog}/bronze/private'
    self.create_key_path_dir()
```

Then I run the notebook using `%run`, and after that I pass the parameters when calling the class itself `gpg_handler = gpg_encryption(catalog = CATALOG, storage_account=STORAGEACCOUNT_NAME )`

But would be nice if someone can explain, how it could be done in as explained in my question or in another way.